# CSS :lang() selector for elements in documents of undetermined language

Tags: css

Is it possible to target elements that have no language set nor inherited, i.e. are in unspecified ("unknown") language?

#### Trivia

HTML document or element language can be set using [HTML `lang`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang) attribute, e.g.:

```
<html lang="en">
<h1>Dictionary</h1>
<dl>
<dt><abbr lang="en-Mors">-... - .--</abbr>
<dd><i lang="fr-Latn">à propos</i>
</dl>
```

or using code(s) in the [`HTTP` Content-language header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Language):

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
[other headers]
Content-language: en,en-Brai,fr-Latn

<html>
<h1>Dictionary</h1>
[rest of document]
```

or it's long deprecated yet still working `<meta http-equiv>` counterpart:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en,en-Brai,fr-Latn">
</head>
<html>
<h1>Dictionary</h1>
[rest of document]
```

In either case using `:lang(en)` CSS selector matches main heading from examples and all other elements that has not explicit `lang` attribute with value not equal or starting with "en".

#### Goal

In case the document is sent **without** `Content-language` HTTP header or `<meta>` element and **without** `lang` attribute, is it possible to match those elements that falls to inevitable "unknown" language?

Plus in document or DOM fragment that has language set by any aforementioned mean, is it possible to use `lang()` CSS selector to match elements with [empty `lang=""` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966317/content-language-header-and-lang-attribute-value-for-mixed-unknown-languages), that effectively 'opts out' of having language?

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
[no content-language header nor meta present]

<html>
<p>I Want to select this. <span>And this.</span></p>
<p lang="">And this.</p>
<p lang="en">Not this. <span lang="">But this again.</span></p>
```

#### What does not work

Neither `:lang()`, `:lang(unknown)`, `:lang('')` nor `:not(:lang(*))` works for this purpose.  Selectors derived from `:not([lang]), [lang='']` would logically give false negative for use-cases with HTTP Content-language header/meta present.

#### Answer requirements

Seeking answer that either gives solution without false negatives or confirms it is not possible with references to specs (or their absence) and explanation why is it so.

---

#### Notes:

When empty `lang=""` attribute is present, targeting it with `[lang=""]` attribute selector works, but feels weird considering there is dedicated `:lang()` pseudo-class for language-related stuff.

Comment: You can't get an HTTP header with CSS. You'll have to do it with JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript

Comment: Sure, not "directly", but since e.g. `:lang(xx)` CSS selector matches all elements without other explicit lang set via attribute in document delivered with `Content-language: xx` HTTP header, it's quite safe to say you can "indirectly".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 2021:** This has been accepted as a bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1281157

---

We provide language range in `:lang()` rule and they are matched against language tags. They've mentioned about supporting asterisks in language ranges:

> Language ranges containing asterisks, for example, must be either correctly escaped or quoted as strings, e.g. :lang(*-Latn) or :lang("*-Latn") [ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#the-lang-pseudo)

And in old 2013 draft:

> Each language range in :lang() must be a valid CSS identifier [CSS21] or consist of an asterisk (* U+002A) immediately followed by an identifier beginning with an ASCII hyphen (U+002D) for the selector to be valid. [ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-selectors4-20130502/#lang-pseudo)

But I can't get `p:lang(\*-US)` to work on Chrome and Firefox on Windows. The rule `p:lang(en\002DUS)` works thought, but `p:lang(en\002D\002A`) does not. Not sure about the status of the support for `special range "*"` in browsers. Also there is no mention of matching `undefined` by the special range "*"  in [Matching of Language Tags](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4647#section-3.3.2).

But,`p:lang(\*)` and `p:not(:lang(\*))` work on iPadOs in both Safari and Chrome. Open this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/howq5pe6/2/) on ipad
[image: worksonIOS]

I think chromium doesn’t support the full `:lang()` feature.

---

**Workaround:** If a little bit of JavaScript is acceptable then you can try following solution:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

function init() {
  if (!document.documentElement.lang) {
    fetchSamePageHeaders(checkHeaderLanguage);
  }
}

//make a lightweight request to the same page to get headers
function fetchSamePageHeaders(callback) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback(request.getAllResponseHeaders());
      }
    }
  };

  // The HEAD method asks for a response identical to that 
  // of a GET request, but without the response body.
  //you can also use 'GET', 'POST' method depending on situation      
  request.open('HEAD', document.location, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function checkHeaderLanguage(headers) {
  //console.log(headers);
  headers = headers.split("\n").map(x => x.split(/: */, 2))
    .filter(x => x[0]).reduce((ac, x) => {
      ac[x[0]] = x[1];
      return ac;
    }, {});

  if (!headers['content-language']) {
    console.log('No language in response header. Marking the html tag.');
    let html = document.querySelector('html');
    html.lang = 'dummyLang';
  } else {
    console.log('The response header has language:' + headers['content-language']);
  }
}
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

p[lang=""],
p:lang(dummyLang) {
  color: darkgreen;
  font-size: 2em;
}

p:lang(en\2dus)::after {
  content: '<= english';
  font-size: 0.5em;
  color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<p>I Want to select this.</p>
<p lang="">And this.</p>
<p lang="en-us">Not this.</p>
<span lang='en-us'>
    <p>Also, not this.</p>
    <p lang="">But, this too.</p>
</span>
```

Here we are using JavaScript to determine if the language has been mentioned in the html tag or in response header. And assigning the html tag `dummyLang` language. You may also want to check meta tags.
For detailed explanation about Getting HTTP headers in javascript and pros and cons of this technique, refer this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/220233/15273968).

Comment: Beside the pros/cons discussion you mention, the `.no-lang-header p:not([lang])` rule would not work correctly if the `p` was nested in another element that had a `lang=".."` attribute which would cause the `p` to inherit it, but the css rule would still select it.

Comment: Good catch! I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for excellent pointers, analysis and bugreport. To wrap it up: IIUC, the only browser core natively supporting `:lang("*")` at this moment (2021-12) is Safari's, right? I assume all browsers on "iPadOs" are technically "skins" of WebKit, so it explains you have seen it working in Chrome in there (?)

Comment: And second loosely related opinion-based question if I may: how do you feel about (working/valid) `:not(:lang("*"))` versus (not-working/invalid) `:lang("")` used for the same purpose? I plan raising an issue at csswg-drafts asking for confirmation of validity of the former and suggesting possible introduction of the later. Does it make sense / is there any blatant obstacle for `:lang("")` matching `<el lang="">` I've missed?

Comment: Yes,  Apple requires every browser to run on WebKit. Even Google Chrome is forced to use WebKit.[ref](https://9to5google.com/2021/05/03/ios-browsers-underpowered-apple/). On other platforms Chromium uses [Blink](http://www.chromium.org/blink)

Comment: As per the specs `:lang(en)` and `:lang("en")` are same. That makes `:lang()` and `:lang("")` same. But `<el>` and `<el lang="">` are not same.  So, there will be confusion whether to treat `:lang()` as `<el>` or `<el lang="">`.

Comment: Good point, yes, it really seems a bit strange. Luckily `:lang()` is still invalid and `:lang("")` not supported, so if there are no hacks in past code-bases abusing it for deliberate rule invalidation, it might be fine after all. Moreover, this analogy could be rephrased in favor of it maybe, because technically `<el lang="">` is equivalent of `<el lang>` (since empty string attribute value is implied), not `<el>` with no attribute. So `:lang()` for `<el lang>` could make some sense after all. (But I admit those are quite obscure arguments.)

Comment: (Like `el[attr=""]` already *matches* both `<el attr>` and `<el attr="">`  - since they are the same). (Learnt from https://stackoverflow.com/a/67952059/540955)

Comment: Makes sense. One more point is how to select elements with lang other than inherited lang. Suppose I want to make other lang, non native, content distinct and stand out. In other words., how to specifically select inherited lang? Also using `:lang(var(--content-lang))` can be made possible.

Comment: FYI, issue filed for CSSWG: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/6915
As for addressing "any" language change in DOM cascade it is also interesting question.  For "sane" markup where there will be no nested elements of the same `lang` value , one could rely simply on `[lang]` selector, but yes, not bulletproof.

Comment: The spec says that the matching is done as per [RFC4647 Matching of Language Tags - section 3.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4647#section-3.3.2). And the RFC says, "*The special range `*` in a language priority list matches any tag.*" So `:lang("*")` needs to be a valid selector.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to come up with a work around, first you can run some js to set the lang attribute of every element with no lang attribute to "xyz" and then select that using css.....

```js
document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(e => {
  if (e.lang == "") e.lang = "xyz";
})
```

```css
p:lang(xyz) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>I Want to select this.</p>
<p lang="">And this.</p>
<p lang="en">Not this.</p>
```

Comment: This would give false match in the "document came with Content-language HTTP header" scenario, and give false matches for nested elements.
This is effectively the same as using plain `*:not([lang]), *[lang=""] { color: red }` CSS rule from the question.